# Rails Server Won't Run on OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to get the rails server to run on OS X Lion. When I type "rails server" into the command line, I get this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

What do you think a solution to the problem is? Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `rails` gem. You could probably do this by running `bundle install` inside that project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Rails Gem?

`gem install rails`

Then do a `gem list` to see if Rails is in there.

It's also important that you be in the proper directory. So if you keep all of your apps in `/apps/` make sure you are in `/apps/my_app` before calling the server command.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby bundled with OS X is too old for Rails 3.

I would recommended using 'rvm' to install the latest stable version of ruby-1.9.2-p260

Since installing ruby requires some compilation, make sure you have a gcc installed. You can install XCode to get an usable gcc.

To install rvm, you need bash, git and curl.

RVM: http://beginrescueend.com/

After that, you can use

```
gem install rails
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The Lion Server looks at a non-default path for the gem file

For example have a look at the first line of /usr/share/devicemgr/backend/devicemgrd:

```
#!/usr/bin/env GEM_HOME=/usr/share/devicemgr/webserver/gems GEM_PATH=/usr/share/devicemgr/webserver/gems RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/ruby
```

So to install the missing gems, make sure to install them at the required path:

```
sudo GEM_HOME=/usr/share/devicemgr/webserver/gems gem install rails
```